# how to load same tableview with different NSArrays depending on uibuttons tapped?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uibutton, tableview, subview

In my app i have a scroll-view and a table-View added as a sub-view and on this scroll view i have multiple menu buttons (UI Button) added as sub-view to my scroll-view.i want to load the table-View with different arrays depending on respective menu button is tapped.Any Ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self PutButtoninScrollView:7];

}
-(void)PutButtoninScrollView:(int)numberOfbuttons
{
    myButton1=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    myButton1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton1.frame=CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 30);
    [myButton1 setTitle:@"दुनिया" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton1 setTag:1];
    myButton1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myButton1];

    myButton2=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    myButton2= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton2.frame=CGRectMake(80, 5, 70, 30);
    [myButton2 setTitle:@"India" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myButton2];
    [self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(160, 35)];
    _myScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];
}

-(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sucessful");        

    if ([myButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"दुनिया"])
    {
        NSLog(@"successful again 1");
    }
    else if ([myButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"भारत"])
    {
        NSLog(@"successful again 2");
    }        
}
```

problem is when i execute the code 
"successful" is displayed. that means ListViewAction method is getting called but my if statement is never executed.

Comment: We can  implement with the help of tag or id pointer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
[myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ListViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: sorry it was (ListViewAction:) in my code.my ListViewAction is working fine. i am getting output string "successful". what i want is to execute "succesful again1" and "successful again2"

Comment: finally found the solution:                                                               -(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender
    {
    
        if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"दुनिया"])
        {
            NSLog(@"successful again");
        }
        else if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"भारत"])
        {
            NSLog(@"successful again1");
        }

    
    }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    -(void)PutButtoninScrollView:(int)numberOfbuttons
{
xPosition=5;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfbuttons;i++)
{

    myButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame=CGRectMake(xPosition, 5, 70, 30);
    myButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
   [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTag:i];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myButton];
    xPosition+=75;
}
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xPosition,35)];
_myScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];
}

  - (void) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
   NSString *strTitle = [sender currentTitle];
 // arrItem have list of array items
   NextView  *detailViewController = [[NextView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
   detailViewController.arrTableView =[arrItem objectAtIndex:[strTitle integerValue]];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: may be the problem is with uibutton added as subview. i have read about UIGestureRecogniser. but dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

-(void)ListViewAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sucessful");

```
if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"दुनिया"])
{
    NSLog(@"successful again 1");
}
else if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"भारत"])
{
    NSLog(@"successful again 2");
}
```

}

Comment: finally it works this way.Just put sender instead of my button in ListViewAction thanx for your help @Ravindhiran